# Naudio: No audible sound

Tags: c#, volume, naudio

I have tried to follow the tutorial here : https://markheath.net/post/fire-and-forget-audio-playback-with
, modifying it a little for my purposes but I can't get to hear any sound out of my speakers.

I also tried directly using the tutorial's code without any success either. Yet, I know the sound file I am using is valid since I can read it through another player.

Here is my modified code:

```
public class AudioPlaybackEngine : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IWavePlayer            outputDevice;
    private readonly MixingSampleProvider   mixer;
    public readonly WaveFormat              Format;

    public AudioPlaybackEngine(int sampleRate = 44100, int channelCount = 2)
    {
        WaveOutEvent    waveOutEvent = new WaveOutEvent();
        outputDevice = waveOutEvent;
        Format = WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(sampleRate, channelCount);
        mixer = new MixingSampleProvider(Format);
        mixer.ReadFully = true;
            waveOutEvent.DeviceNumber = -1;
        Logger.writeLine("Selected sound device : " + waveOutEvent.DeviceNumber, "AudioPlaybackEngine");
        outputDevice.Init(mixer);
        outputDevice.Play();
    }

    public float    MasterVolume
    {
        get { return outputDevice.Volume; }
        set { outputDevice.Volume = value; }
    }

    /// <summary> Only use this if you want to play a sound a single time (not cached) </summary>
    public void PlaySound(string fileName)
    {
        var input = new AudioFileReader(fileName);
        AddMixerInput(new AutoDisposeFileReader(input));
    }

    private ISampleProvider ConvertToRightChannelCount(ISampleProvider input)
    {
        if (input.WaveFormat.Channels == mixer.WaveFormat.Channels)
        {
            return input;
        }
        if (input.WaveFormat.Channels == 1 && mixer.WaveFormat.Channels == 2)
        {
            return new MonoToStereoSampleProvider(input);
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException("Not yet implemented this channel count conversion");
    }

    /// <summary> Play new sounds here using new SoundInstance(cachedSound) </summary>
    public void     PlaySoundInstance(ISampleProvider soundInstance)
    {
        AddMixerInput(soundInstance);
    }

    public void     StopSoundInstance(ISampleProvider soundInstance)
    {
        mixer.RemoveMixerInput(soundInstance);
    }

    private void    AddMixerInput(ISampleProvider input)
    {
        mixer.AddMixerInput(ConvertToRightChannelCount(input));
    }

    private void    RemoveMixerInput(ISampleProvider input)
    {
        mixer.RemoveMixerInput(input);
    }

    public void     Dispose()
    {
        outputDevice.Dispose();
    }

    public static readonly AudioPlaybackEngine Instance = new AudioPlaybackEngine(44100, 2);
}

public class CachedSound
{
    public float[]      AudioData { get; private set; }
    public WaveFormat   WaveFormat { get; private set; }

    public CachedSound(string audioFileName)
    {
        AudioFileReader         afr = new AudioFileReader(audioFileName);
        WaveToSampleProvider    wts = new WaveToSampleProvider(new MediaFoundationResampler(new SampleToWaveProvider(afr), AudioPlaybackEngine.Instance.Format));
        int samplesRead;
        var wholeFile = new List<float>((int)(afr.Length / 4));
        var readBuffer= new float[wts.WaveFormat.SampleRate * wts.WaveFormat.Channels];
        while((samplesRead = wts.Read(readBuffer,0,readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            wholeFile.AddRange(readBuffer.Take(samplesRead));
        }
        WaveFormat = wts.WaveFormat;
        AudioData = wholeFile.ToArray();
    }
}

/// <summary> Class using a cached buffer as data and providing access to volume </summary>
public class SoundInstance : ISampleProvider
{
    public readonly CachedSound     cachedSound;
    public long                     Position = 0;
    public float                    Volume = 1f;
    public bool                     LoopingEnabled = true;
    public bool                     StopASAP = false;

    public      SoundInstance(CachedSound cachedSound)
    {
        this.cachedSound = cachedSound;
    }

    public int  Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int totalBytesRead = 0;

        while (totalBytesRead < count)
        {
            if (StopASAP)
                return 0;
            // we have reached the end of the file
            if (cachedSound.AudioData.Length == Position)
            {
                if (LoopingEnabled)
                    Position = 0; // reset position if looping enabled
                else
                    return totalBytesRead; // otherwise, stop reading.
            }

            // copy data
            buffer[totalBytesRead + offset] = cachedSound.AudioData[Position] * Volume;

            ++Position;
            ++totalBytesRead;
        }
        return totalBytesRead;
    }

    public WaveFormat WaveFormat { get { return cachedSound.WaveFormat; } }
}

// This class automatically disposes the file reader that it contains.
class AutoDisposeFileReader : ISampleProvider
{
    private readonly AudioFileReader reader;
    private bool isDisposed;
    public AutoDisposeFileReader(AudioFileReader reader)
    {
        this.reader = reader;
        this.WaveFormat = reader.WaveFormat;
    }

    public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (isDisposed)
            return 0;
        int read = reader.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        if (read == 0)
        {
            reader.Dispose();
            isDisposed = true;
        }
        return read;
    }

    public WaveFormat WaveFormat { get; private set; }
}

public class SoundManager
{
    private Dictionary<string, CachedSound>     _soundsInMemory = new Dictionary<string, CachedSound>();
    private List<SoundInstance>                 _soundsInstances = new List<SoundInstance>();

    public                  SoundManager()
    {

    }

    public void             unloadSound(string soundName)
    {
        if (_soundsInMemory.ContainsKey(soundName))
            _soundsInMemory.Remove(soundName);
    }

    public void             loadSound(string soundName, string fileName)
    {
        _soundsInMemory.Add(soundName, new CachedSound(fileName));
    }

    public CachedSound      getLoadedSound(string soundName)
    {
        if (_soundsInMemory.ContainsKey(soundName))
            return _soundsInMemory[soundName];
        return null;
    }

    public SoundInstance    createSoundInstance(string soundName, float volume = 1f, bool enableLooping = true)
    {
        SoundInstance       sound = new SoundInstance(getLoadedSound(soundName));
        sound.Volume = volume;
        sound.LoopingEnabled = enableLooping;
        //_soundsInstances.Add(sound);
        return sound;
    }
}
```

And here is the way I start the sound for the moment:

```
            SoundManager    sm = new SoundManager();

            string          soundName = "test";
            sm.loadSound(soundName, "sounds/1.wav");

            SoundInstance   si = sm.createSoundInstance(soundName);
            AudioPlaybackEngine.Instance.PlaySoundInstance(si);
```

The interesting bit is that I can see the green bar moving up and down in the "Volume mixer" of Windows but nothing is shown in the Settings panel->Speakers' Volume (while other player apps do show something here in that last panel).

Please help?

Comment: At the moment it looks like the volume is set to 1f. Can you set it to something higher like 50 or 100f?

Comment: I have tried modifying it to 100f but nothing outputs from my speakers either despite the fact the "Volume mixer" seems to show a fully saturated green bar for my application. Still nothing in the "Settings panel", and, no sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to remove :

```
 ̶p̶u̶b̶l̶i̶c̶ ̶s̶t̶a̶t̶i̶c̶ ̶r̶e̶a̶d̶o̶n̶l̶y̶ ̶A̶u̶d̶i̶o̶P̶l̶a̶y̶b̶a̶c̶k̶E̶n̶g̶i̶n̶e̶ ̶I̶n̶s̶t̶a̶n̶c̶e̶ ̶=̶ ̶n̶e̶w̶ ̶A̶u̶d̶i̶o̶P̶l̶a̶y̶b̶a̶c̶k̶E̶n̶g̶i̶n̶e̶(̶4̶4̶1̶0̶0̶,̶ ̶2̶)̶;̶
```

And **instantiate it in the same thread** than the one which will call PlaySound().